# How to calculate the monodromy matrix for a system of nonautonomous nonlinear differential equations?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, nonlinear-system, nonlinear-dynamics

I am interested in analyzing the stability of the periodic orbits resulting from the Van der Pol system periodically perturbed by a time-dependent external forcing. Mathematically it would be the following system of nonlinear differential equations

$\begin{equation} \left \{ 
\begin{aligned}
\frac{dx}{dt} & =  \mu \left ( x - \frac{x^3}{3} - y \right ) + \varepsilon\cos(\omega t), \\
\frac{dy}{dt} & =  \frac{x}{\mu}.
\end{aligned} 
\right.
\end{equation}$

When the system is autonomous, i.e $\varepsilon = 0$, I only have to solve the matrix differential equation $\dot{\Phi}(t) = D_{x}\mathbf{f}(X(t))\Phi(t)$ with the initial condition $\Phi(0) = \mathbf{I}$, where $D_{x}\mathbf{f}$ is the Jacobian matrix of the vector field that defines the system of differential equations.  $\Phi(T)$ is the monodromy matrix of the periodic orbit $X(t)$, where $T$ represents its period. How can I calculate the monodromy matrix of the non-autonomous system?